# Wake m2e Maven builder up when XSDs imported by WSDLs are modified

Tags: eclipse, maven, cxf, m2e

I have a WSDL first CXF server project in which the WSDL imports several XSDs.
Some of these XSDs, in turn, refer to other XSDs.

The maven builder correctly detects workspace resource changes on the parent WSDL and instantaneously regenerates (cxf-codegen) the various derived resources (classes).

When instead, the a child XSD is modified, the m2e builder feels unconcerned. Of course I can periodically "run as Maven..." but that's not convenient.

Any suggestion?

Comment: In my experience, I don't do that sort of thing because when the messages change, the code to work with them also has to change. (Mind you, I tend to mostly do Java-first and then hand-audit the resulting XSDs…)

Comment: @DonalFellows, Forgot to say: I'm developing the server at the moment.  So that all changes are welcome for now.  I'm actually constantly controlling whether my XSD changes (jaxb:javadoc included) make sense on the Java side or not, and it's awkward to always try to remember "BTW, did I regenerate this time?".  This is where I'm coming from.

Comment: I know it's difficult, and if I had a good suggestion I'd have done a real answer. It might help a bit if you put your XSD and WSDL in a separate Maven module so that it's more cleanly separated. Maven doesn't need it, but it makes Eclipse much happier. No idea if that would solve your problem though. :-)

Comment: @DonalFellows, Thx. In theory this should be straightforward.  1/ understand whether cxf-codegen detects children XSD modifications. 2/ understand whether m2e picks this info up exhaustively.  Before I delve into the code I hoped someone would give me a cheaper answer. But if ever manage to get to the bottom of this one, I'll document it here below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF's plugin (at this time) doesn't automatically detect and record the schemas that are imported and thus would not recognize any changes.   However, the maven configuration does allow a `<dependencies>` config element of the wsdlOptions to allow specifying by hand which other files the plugin should look at for changes.   See the CXF testutils/pom.xml:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/testutils/pom.xml

for some examples.